# How to read float input without knowing size in java?

Tags: java, arrays, input, java.util.scanner

Sample Input:

```
9.1 9.0 8.9 8.8 9.4 7.9 8.6 9.8
```

Here is my code for getting input.

I dont know how to get this type of input without knowing the number of inputs.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Diving_Competition
 */
public class Diving_Competition {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Float> lst = new ArrayList<Float>();

        while (in.hasNextFloat()) {
            lst.add(in.nextFloat());
        }

        System.out.print(lst);

        in.close();
    }
}
```

This loop runs infinite time. How to get input in a single line without knowing its size?

I'm from python background

Comment: This loop does not 'run infinite time'. It will stop as soon as `hasNextFloat()` returns false, which it will certainly do at the end of the input if not before when something else turns up in it. There is no problem here to solve.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
        at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:461)
        at Diving_Competition.main(Diving_Competition.java:15)

Comment: That's more proof that the loop does not run indefinitely. If that's your real question you should have asked it. But this code does not call `parseFloat()` and does not throw this exception.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are numerical inputs, your code will not exit the `while` loop because the condtion `in.hasNextFloat()` is satisfied.

Assuming you are entering the sample in the terminal: To exit the loop, just enter any non-numerical value like `a` or enter the EOF-command. In Unix this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and in Windows it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (not sure about Windows-Command)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't java in a bit but I think this works. I read the whole line and separate them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Diving_Competition
 */
public class read {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String string = in.nextLine();
        String[] stringLst = string.split(" ");
        ArrayList<Float> numLst = new ArrayList<Float>();
        
        for (String num : stringLst) {
            numLst.add(Float.parseFloat(num));
        }
        
        System.out.print(numLst);
    
        in.close();
    }
}
```

[image: Image of project here]

Comment: 9.1  9.0  8.9  8.8  9.4  7.9  8.6  9.8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
        at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:461)
        at Diving_Competition.main(Diving_Competition.java:15)

Comment: I got exception like empty string

Comment: That's because this code is worse than what you already posted. It assumes every token is a real number, and wastes the `Scanner` by only using it to process lines. Do not use.

Comment: Can anyone correct and send it.  I'm new to Java Begginer

Comment: This worked for me but it uses the console to get the input. How are you giving the input?

Comment: I'm using eclipse so I'll have to look into how vs code works. I am getting the same error on vs code.

Comment: I got it to work in vs code. The java file has to be apart of a project though.

Comment: Don't bother with this. See the answer by @csalmhof.

Comment: It did work in vs code. The java file has to be a part of a java project.

Comment: My java file also be a part of the java project can you share your screenshot?

Comment: I've attached the image to the answer.

Comment: @CalebSadler It will work as long as the only tokens in the input are real numbers. It will barf with this exception as soon as they aren't. I've already stated this.

Comment: are we not supposed to assume an input of reals?

Comment: I added a screenshot and I added one more condition then only it works

Comment: @CalebSadler Practical programs do not throw exceptions in unexpected situations. This is not controversial.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure out such issues is either by debugger OR use console to print helpful information. Your program is perfectly fine, it hangs because it is expecting an input that needs to be entered (unless you want to scan input as program args then its a different question).

Here I made a simple change in your program

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Float> lst = new ArrayList<Float>();

    while (in.hasNextFloat()) {
        float x = in.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Number Entered: " + x);
        lst.add(x);
    }

    System.out.print(lst);

    in.close();
}
```

and here is console output

```sh
2.3
Number Entered: 2.3
re
[2.3]
```

Notice how to end the input, I had to enter *non-float* letters. If I don't enter that, the program will continue to take input from the console, *one-by-one*.

That being said, from your question it looks like you want to get a *line* of float input from console. If that the case, then you should read by line and parse it based on "space" character.